# Since gravity is like an indent on a piece of paper (the space/time matrix) to a marble, can the black hole eventually suck in the matrix?

Tags: black-hole, gravity, space-time

Can a black hole suck in time? People claim that if you were to put a bowling ball on a trampoline and rolled much smaller balls through the deppression, some would stay in "orbit", some would roll through (if they were fast enough) and the others would just get stuck at the bottom. And if you put something that was heavy enough, the trampoline would snap. So could a black hole suck in the matrix??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot going on in the body of the question, so I'll try and be as specific as I can in addressing the separate points.

Can a black hole suck in time? No. It changes the passage of time locally due to its immense gravity crushing frequency (our observation of time), but it can't "eat" time. Time is an observational property, and has no physical feature to be eaten.

Can a black hole lead to a snap in space-time such that there's a hole for stuff to pass through into some unknown "layer"? Possibly, but the answer isn't beyond theory at this point as we can't see past the event horizon. Such a "rip" into a new "layer" is one theory on how this universe was created, with the big bang being the white hole end of a black hole in another universe (layer).

Could the black hole suck in the matrix (space-time) itself? No, gravity only *distorts* space-time, so the matrix is only stretched and not consumed.

Answer (score 0):

The ball on a trampoline is a neat visualization of spacetime, but it is only an analogy. The more massive an object is, the greater its gravity. A person has very little gravity compared to our Earth, so the Earth would make the trampoline sink further than a person. The same applies to a comparison between our Sun and the Earth. The Sun has much greater gravity than the Earth, so the Sun makes the trampoline sink further than the Earth. The singularity at the center of a black hole has infinite gravity, and thus, will stretch that trampoline infinitely.

It looks like this:

[image]